# Exception during UIDAI authentication

Tags: java, authentication, exception

We are trying to run the sample application of UIDAI Aadhaar authentication in java, while running the code we provide a valid aadhaar no. and the name and clicked on **Authentication** button. In response we get an alert with the error.

[image]
The exception on console

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: 
POST http://auth.uidai.gov.in/1.6/public/6/9/MMZS5K8bEkGWFQe6y_ruBu9tFR2yQFQkqmECCpp9veRawhue1oGpa4s 
returned a response status of 503
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP Status Code 503** represent that **Service Unavailable**

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Please check that UIDAI Aadhaar authentication API is up and running.